# how to give target="_blank" to all a tags in html

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

i have an html page with alot of links using `a` tag. i want to open all links in different tabs, instead of setting `target="_blank"` in all a tags, is there anyway to do it like below in css:

```html
a{target="_blank";}
```

can anyone please tell, thanks in advance.

Comment: i dont know if there is, but the probability is close to zero

Comment: You cant do these things in CSS. However, you can use HTML and Javascript. CSS is for layout, which isn't really used for opening things in new tabs

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Specify a default target for all hyperlinks and forms on a page:

```
<head>
  <base target="_blank">
</head>
```

[source](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_base_target.asp)

Comment: thanks, one more doubt, will this cause any problem to the modals or tabs which has a tag

Comment: not sure but I guess if there's a problem you can overwrite it with the default `target="_self"` in the specific a tag which is the default behaviour

Comment: yes, there is a problem, while clicking the modal its simply opening a new tab even though the modal is also opening

Comment: well, you can use something like onclick="return false;" or onclick="(function(e){e.preventDefault();})(event)" to stop your anchor tags from their default behavior

Answer (score 2):

you can also add a small script

```
<script>
document.querySelectorAll('a')
    .forEach(function(elem) {
        elem.setAttribute('target', '_blank');
    })
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If all code is in a single HTML file it would be easiest to run `CTRL/CMD+F` and add `target="_blank"`to them. This would be very easy to so in Sublime Text for example.

This could also be easily accomplished with PHP.

Usually, CSS is used to style the HTML markup; therefore I see no real value in adding the target with CSS.

I suggest you think about if you actually want to use `target="_blank"` on all links as this is generally considered bad practice. See https://www.searchenginejournal.com/when-not-to-use-target_blank-link-attribute/19924/

Also, **always** use `rel="noopener"` or `rel="noreferrer"` to your `target="_blank"` as omitting these is a **security risk**! See https://web.dev/external-anchors-use-rel-noopener/